# PL/SQL Boolean Datatype in Oracle

Tags: oracle, types, plsql, boolean

I was trying to execute below code on Oracle; intended to print boolean value. it is not complining. any help?

```
DECLARE
 v_bool BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
 IF (v_bool IS NULL) THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('By default the value is NULL');
 ELSEIF (v_bool = TRUE) THEN
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('By default the value is TRUE');
 ELSE
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('By default the value is FALSE');
 END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Sorry,what compilation error are you facing? I didn't see the question properly at the first sight!

Comment: "it is not complining.": Do you mean *compiling* or *complaining*?

Comment: As well as replacing `elseif` as Codo said, you don't have to explicitly compare the boolean value to true or false, though that's perfectly valid. You can simplify it to `elsif v_bool then`, and a test for false could be written as `elsif not v_bool then`.

Answer (score 6):

Your code doesn't compile. Instead of:

```
ELSEIF ...
```

it should be:

```
ELSIF ...
```

Once you get that right, the output will be:

```
By default the value is NULL
```

(All variables are initialized to NULL in PL/SQL.)